# Getting Unable to find specification exception while running Concordion Fixure file

Tags: java, concordion

I have kept fixure and html (specification) file under the same package 'test/java/com/mypckg/'. I'm using 2.0.2 concordion version.

But when I run the test I get below mentioned error. Please help me in resolving this.

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find specification: 'com/mypckg/Testing.html' or 'com/mypckg/Testing.xhtml' or 'com/mypckg/Testing.md' or 'com/mypckg/Testing.markdown'

```
at org.concordion.Concordion.<init>(Concordion.java:64)
at org.concordion.internal.ConcordionBuilder.build(ConcordionBuilder.java:310)
at org.concordion.internal.FixtureRunner.<init>(FixtureRunner.java:19)
at org.concordion.integration.junit4.ConcordionRunner.<init>(ConcordionRunner.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

I have tried to debug Concordion.class resource path sent till here is proper.

Below is my code.

`@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)`
`public class TestingFixture {`

```
Testing system = new Testing();

    public String greetingFor(String firstName) {
        return "Hello " + firstName + "!";
    }
```

}

Comment: I am able to resolve this by modifying the package structure slightly. Old: Fixture and html (specification)  file was under, 'src/test/com/mypckg/TestingFixture.java'  New: Now I have kept TestingFixture.java under 'src/test/concordion/' and html file under /resources/concordion/.